# Getting the Ajax data to the DataTable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, datatables

I am using angularJS and [DataTables](https://datatables.net). I want to load the DataTable when the call is finished. I got some sample code at DataTables page, but don't understand how I am supposed to feed the DataTable with the actual data from the call. This is the code so far:

```
     ImageService.getImages().then(function (value) {

        $('#adminTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": "data/objects.txt",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "ImageName" },
                { "data": "ImageCategory" },
                { "data": "Image" }
            ]
        });
    };
```

The returned Json looks like this

```
  [
    {
        "_id": "59fe0d54986fb50500005a76",
        "ImageName": "test55",
        "ImageCategory": "test77",
        "Image": [
            "59fe0d52986fb50500005a75"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "59fdaee7986fb50500005696",
        "ImageName": "ghjskfda",
        "ImageCategory": "Red",
        "Image": [
            "59fdaee5986fb50500005695"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "59fcbea1986fb5050000504a",
        "ImageName": "test4",
        "ImageCategory": "Light",
        "Image": [
            "59fcbe9f986fb50500005049"
        ]


     }
    ]
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You are pretty close: Replace `"ajax": "data/objects.txt",` with `data: value,` ...

Comment: replaced data with value, got this error: DataTables warning: table id=adminTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: yes! got it workin!!

Comment: is there any way of making the Name a anchor tag and on click call angular scope method?